# How bert [cls] can collect the relevant information from the rest of the hidden states

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, language-model

How bert [cls] can collect the relevant information from the rest of the hidden states.??. Does [cls] has mlm information?  If i train my bert using only mlm, in this case cls works?

Answer (score 2):

The self-attention takes care of that, what self-attention does is basically a clever collection and combination of information from the hidden states at the previous network layer.

Nevertheless, something needs to "tell" the `[CLS]` vector to collect the information about the rest of the sentence. When only using the masked-language-model objective, the `[CLS]` vector does not play any special role. However, as the [RoBERTa paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11692) shows, it does not need a special pertaining, and using the vector during fine-tuning provides enough training signal.